# SQL CASE: Does the order of the WHEN statements matter?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I am using PHP to generate a SQL query that needs to be ordered in a custom way. I am generating a `CASE` block with a number of `WHEN` statements that assign a number ranking. The `WHEN` statements that are included are contingent on how much information I have available for querying. For example, if I have a phone available, I will generate three `WHEN` statements:

`WHEN phone = '(202) 555-5555' AND last_name = 'Smith' and first_name = 'John' THEN 1`

`WHEN phone = '(202) 555-5555' AND last_name = 'Smith' THEN 2`

`WHEN phone = '(202) 555-5555' THEN 3`

So I am ranking based on how close the match is, and I am valuing the parameters the same (a match on phone, first name, and last name should be ranked on the same tier as a match on address, first name and last name). However, after generating these statements for multiple pieces of information (phone, address, etc), my `WHEN` statements will be all out of order; the `THEN 1` terminated clauses will be separated from each other, same for `THEN 2` and so on. I could put them in order, but that would make my PHP more verbose and ugly.

**TL;DR?**

So the **short question** is: Does the order of the `WHEN` statements in a `CASE` statement matter? Does SQL (I'm using Oracle) go with the first match or does it evaluate all of the possibilities and assign the highest ranking?

Comment: Yes - the first `WHEN` condition that matches will be used - if you happen to have multiple that match, it depends on the order in which they appear

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Works like a fall thru scenario, if a WHEN satisfies the condition then it stops checking for the rest of the conditions.

Comment: `does it evaluate all of the possibilities and assign the highest ranking?`  =No (if that hasn't already been made clear)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, the order of the case statements *does* matter.  The first matching row will be the one returned.

So, this statement:

```
(CASE WHEN phone = '(202) 555-5555' AND last_name = 'Smith' and first_name = 'John' THEN 1
      WHEN phone = '(202) 555-5555' AND last_name = 'Smith' THEN 2
      WHEN phone = '(202) 555-5555' THEN 3
 END)
```

Could return 1, 2, or 3 (or `NULL`).  The following will always return 3 (or `NULL`) because the last two conditions will never be processed:

```
(CASE WHEN phone = '(202) 555-5555' THEN 3
      WHEN phone = '(202) 555-5555' AND last_name = 'Smith' THEN 2
      WHEN phone = '(202) 555-5555' AND last_name = 'Smith' and first_name = 'John' THEN 1
 END)
```