# How does when function work with multiple matching cases?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

does spark when function is consistently return the first match?
for example,

```
val df = spark.sql("SELECT 1 as a")

df.withColumn("a",when($"a">0,1).when($"a">0.5,2)).show()
```

does it always return the first 'when' match consistently?

or better practice is to do that way:

```
df.withColumn("a",when($"a">0,1).otherwise(when($"a">0.5,2)).show()
```

what is better practice to use?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation (especially the example) suggest that the first match is taken :

> Evaluates a list of conditions and returns one of multiple possible
>   result expressions. If otherwise is not defined at the end, null is
>   returned for unmatched conditions.
>         // Example: encoding gender string column into integer.
>
> // Scala:
>         people.select(
>               when(people("gender") === "male", 0)
>               .when(people("gender") === "female", 1)
>               .otherwise(2))

EDIT:

Although this example uses disjunct cases,  it's standard SQL that the first match is taken, see e.g. https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/43353 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/22641095/1138523

Comment: I saw the docs, their example are with 2 conditions that cannot be match both,
they dont say the first one is taken, if i have match on multiple conditions.

Comment: true! In (standard) SQL it should take first match. But it would be nice to see this somewhere documented